# Rich text excerpt

Tags: text, format, wysiwyg

I am using WYSISWG text editor to write post for my website, it generates text with various formatting tags like

```
<strong></strong>
<em></em>
<ul><li>
</li></ul>
```

I want to make excerpt from this, but when I just cut text, it will cut it at random place and it can break website layout. Any ways to to excerpts from rich text?